# MVC with one controller different view folder

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controller

**UPDATE - Reworded question**

I am going to use JQuery Mobile for the mobile side of a new MVC applciation that I am building. Since JQuery Mobile will manage the different devices on the client side I need only one mobile view for each page that I create. This will simplify the number of views required and basically boil it down to mobile and desktop views, for now.

I would like to have one controller call 2 different views, with the caveat being the views are in different folders (mobile and desktop). For example, the Index method on the controller would call a build view path method

```
return View(BuildViewPath("Index"));
```

It works if my folders are like this but I hate to have to keep creating device subfolders for each controller view

```
Views
   Login
       Desktop
          Index.aspx
       Mobile
          Index.aspx
```

For my login controller I would like the views would be structured as follows:

```
Views
    Desktop
        Login
            Index.aspx
    Mobile
        Login
            Index.aspx
```

I tried returning "~/Views/Desktop/Login/Index" but that did not work.I understand about the naming convention {controler}{view} so I can see why this isn't right.

Is this possible or is it not a good idea? If not, what is the best practice for organizing a project for 2 different view paths. Remember, I am looking for one controller.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application